# "Was failed" or "has been failed"

Tags: phrase-requests, sentence

I'm a developer. In our system, we have "jobs". When a job fails, I write

> "Job **has been** failed".

But a fellow-developer says that this should be:

> "Job **was** failed."

So, what is the best way to say it?

Comment: "Job failed" is customary. Neither of the above is grammatically correct. "The job has failed" is.

Answer (score 2):

> That all depends on the **tense** and **passivity** of these duo sentences. Let's put some focus unto it.

---

**Your view:**

> Job has been failed.

This is the passive form of "Job has failed", which indicates that job failed **recently.**

---

**Your fellow-developer's view:**

> Job was failed.

This is the passive form of "Job had failed", which indicates that job failed long time ago, **[not recently].**

Therefore, it depends on both of you, which tense to use. If job was failed recently, use first example of your own. If the job was failed long time ago, use the latter option of your fellow-developer.

Comment: I agree with you. The point is that the job is considered to be self sustaining so, if it fails, it is 'responsible' for failing itself. If a job is stopped because of someone's intervention we tend to say that the job was _abandoned_ or _cancelled_ **by** that person but the job _fails_ all on its own. In the case of a member of the IT team they could be said to have _failed_ to prevent the failure of the job but could also be said to have _been failed_ by the support contactors if hardware problems caused the job to fail. The situation of the member of the team and the job are similar.